# Springboot Deserializing ">" symbol as &gt; and "<" as &lt;

Tags: spring-boot, json-deserialization, fasterxml

I have a post api built in springboot with request body as follows

```
{ "value" : ">" }
```

When this value is passed to the api as payload, the deserilized value in the controller is coming as &gt; .

the request body in java is as follows

```
public class MyData {

private String value;
//getters //setters 

}
```

How can I tell spring to deserialize it as is and not to convert it.

Appreciate your help... :)

Comment: which version spring boot you are using ? it works for me with `2.3.9.RELEASE`

Comment: I am using 2.2.4-RELEASE